# geth error exceeds block gas limit"

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, nft, cpp-ethereum

im running a local geth node to increase transactions speeds for nfts minting however during a nft mint that had a contract set Gas limit to 250k there was gas wars and eth gwei went up  to 500 gwei because it has a hyped up mint. and i tried to send the transaction with 100gwei and 15 priority and instantly got that error message -3200 exceeds block gas limit.
ive seen some commands but not sure if they are the right ones.
--miner.gaslimit
--miner.gastarget
--targetgaslimit

Comment: Can you show the code used to send the transactions? It seems you were changing the gas limit and not the gas price.